# Traffic Light Detection by using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

```
 import cv2 import numpy as np
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read() # frame olarak goruntuyu aldık
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_yellow = np.array([20,0,0])
    upper_yellow = np.array([40,255,255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    img = cv2.medianBlur(res, 5)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(cimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,                  
                     param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=20, maxRadius=30)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
         cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
         cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imshow('detected circles', cimg)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my codes. I want to detect traffic light on live stream by using image processing . Firstly I will detect yellow colour, after that I will find circle on mask image .
I think, The error is occuring at the  HoughCircles parameters.
But there is a error called:

Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/yavuzhan/PythonProgramlama/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 52, in _wrapfunc return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'round'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/media/yavuzhan/DATA/2017-2018/Otonom Araç Projesi/Dosya/Otonom Araç Yazılım/renkalgilama.py", line 30, in circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

Comment: I think instead of using `circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))` you should use `circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")`. Additionally, you should also check if any circles were found, using, `if circles is not None`

Comment: I have done what your said . But now there is a another error called Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/yavuzhan/DATA/2017-2018/Otonom Araç Projesi/Dosya/Otonom Araç Yazılım/renkalgilama.py", line 29, in <module>
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Did you add the check if any circles were found? You can also use `print(len(circles))`. Also, `cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT` should be `cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT`

Comment: I checked . When ı put the code(print(type(circles))) before circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles)) , it returns <class 'NoneType'> but , when ı put the code after that , it does not return , because  circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles)) the code does not  run.

Comment: I think the error is occuring at the code whic is " circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")"

Comment: As I have clearly mentioned, check if any circles were found by using `if circles is not None`, before calling `circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")` which you haven't tried. `print(len(circles))` will tell you how many circles were found, which in this case seems to be zero. It gives you `NoneType` error because it most probably didn't find any circles. Try debugging if this doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried what you said and the problem is solved but now there is another problem :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/yavuzhan/DATA/2017-2018/Otonom Araç Projesi/Dosya/Otonom Araç Yazılım/renkalgilama.py", line 34, in <module>
    cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: If it solved your problem, I will put it as an answer, you can accept it. [The second problem is also trivial if you read the docs.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting `AttributeError: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'round'` because `circles` in `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,               param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=20, maxRadius=30)` was empty. This is because `cv2.HoughCircles` didn't find any circles. You should put a check for `circles` like `if circles is not None` before using it later.

PS. Try to tune the parameters so that `cv2.HoughCircles` finds circles you can work with. And try to read the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) to pin point the problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you Guys . The problem is solved . I have did what Rick said :) Again . Thank you .